# Insert Pagination in Search database. PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm a beginner in PHP MySQL, I have both working and separate Search Employee Engine and View All Employee with pagination but right now I want to merge this both file.

I want to insert the pagination function to search my engine but I don't know how to do it (although it's working in my view all employee).

**Here is my View All Employee file:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{ header("Location: index.php");}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);   

$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY agentLname ASC";

if(isset($_SESSION['usertype']) && $_SESSION['usertype'] == 'Admin') {

?>

<html>
<body>

    <div class="row mt">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="content-panel">

    <?php 
    if($result = mysql_query($sql)){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    ?> 


    <table class="table table-hover">
    <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Employees<h5 style="float:right;"><a href="addnew.php" style="color:#ffffff;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-theme02" ><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Add New Agent</button></h5></h3></a>

       <hr>
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Agent Code</th>
     <th>Full Name</th>
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>Phone No.</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Account Type</th>
     <th>User Type</th>
     <th>IP Address</th>
     <th></th>
     <th></th>

    <?php
    }  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {  ?>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentCode']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentLname'].',  '.$row['agentFname'].' '.$row['aSuffixName'].' '.$row['agentMname']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentAddress']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentContact']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentGender']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['user_type']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['location_type']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ip_add']; ?></td>

    <td>
    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id'];  ?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
    </td></tr>

    <?php      
        }
     }      
     ?>    


                          </tbody>  
                      </table>
                  </div><!-- /content-panel -->
              </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
          </div><!-- /row -->

</body>
</html>

<?php
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
} // end if user is not admin
?>
```

**Here is my Search Employee file**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{ header("Location: index.php"); }
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);   

if(isset($_SESSION['usertype']) && $_SESSION['usertype'] == 'Admin') {

?>

          <div class="row mt">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
            <div class="form-panel">                                
                      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Search Employee</h3>
                     <p style="font-size:13pt;color: black;padding-left: 1em;">You  may search either by first or last name</p>
                      <!-- INLINE FORM ELELEMNTS -->

                      <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post"  id="searchform">
                      <div class="form-group">

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Input First or Last Name" style="width: 300px;">
                      <h5 style="float:right;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme02" name="submit" ><i class="fa fa-check">Search Employee</i></button></h5>

                      </div>



                    <?php

        echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">";
        echo " <hr><thead><tr>";
        echo "<th>Agent Code</th>";
        echo "<th>Full Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Address</th>";
        echo "<th>Gender</th>";
        echo "<th>Account Type</th>";
        echo "<th>User Type</th>";
        echo "<th>IP Address</th>"; 
        echo "<th></th>";
        echo "<th></th>";     
        echo " </tr></thead>";       

         if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if(preg_match("/[A-Z  | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){


$name=$_POST['name'];

$sql1="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE  agentFname LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR agentLname LIKE '%" . $name  ."%'";
$result=mysql_query($sql1); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $aCode = $row['agentCode'];
      $aFName  = $row['agentFname'];
      $aMName  = $row['agentMname'];
      $aLName = $row['agentLname'];
      $aAddress = $row['agentAddress'];
      $aGender = $row['agentGender'];
      $a_type = $row['user_type'];
      $u_type = $row['location_type'];
      $ipadd = $row['ip_add'];
      $ID = $row['user_id'];

      echo "<tbody><tr>";
      echo "<td>".$aCode."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$aLName." ".$aFName." ".$aMName. "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$aAddress."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$aGender."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$a_type."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$u_type."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$ipadd."</td>";
      echo "</form>"; 
      ?>

  <td>
      <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>
      <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id'];  ?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
  </td>

     <?php                                                                                                                                                                       
  } //while

  }

  }//submit

        ?>

            </div><!-- /form-panel -->

    </div>
      </div>



  <?php
  } else {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
  } // end if user is not admin
  ?>
```

**Here is the function.php where the pagination script allocated**

```
<?php

function pagination($query, $per_page = 3,$page = 1, $url = '?'){        
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total = $row['num'];
    $adjacents = "2"; 

    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

    $prev = $page - 1;                          
    $next = $page + 1;
    $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a> </li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
            }
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
            }
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
        }else{
            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
    }


    return $pagination;
} 
?>
```

Comment: That a lot of code, can you simplify the issue/code? Also you should have exit after `header("Location: index.php");`. Additionally `not working` isn't too useful, not working how, error, no results...

Comment: Hi @chris85 , Actually I have problem in inserting the pagination in my search engine. I would like to transfer the pagination in my search engine but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by this way

```
<?php

function pagination($num, $per_page = 3,$page = 1, $url = '?'){        

    $total = $num;
    $adjacents = "2"; 

    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

    $prev = $page - 1;                          
    $next = $page + 1;
    $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a> </li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
            }
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
            }
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
        }else{
            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
    }


    return $pagination;
} 
?>
```

add this option below-

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "yourhost");
define("DB_USER", "DBuser");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "passwrod");
define("DB_DATABASE", "DB name");
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE );
?>
```

Or you can use here your own database connection file

//set pagination

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE  agentFname LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR agentLname LIKE '%" . $name  ."%'";
$num = mysqli_num_rows($conn->query($query));

$per_page = 3;
$page = 1;
$url = 'pagination.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['start'])){
    $start = $_REQUEST['start'];
}else{

    $start = '0';
}



$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE  agentFname LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR agentLname LIKE '%" . $name  ."%' LIMIT $start, $per_page ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //all info you want to print
    $aCode = $row['agentCode'];
      $aFName  = $row['agentFname'];
      .
      .
} 

echo  pagination($num, $per_page = 3,$page = 1, $url = '?');
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have problem in this <br/> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\CIS\search.php on line 177
<br/>
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\CIS\search.php on line 177

Comment: I already fix the connection sir but it seems having problem in like this:
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Comment: I chage the $num to like this: 
 $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);

Comment: use this again $num = mysqli_num_rows($conn->query($query));

Comment: Is this PDO? can you change into old type connection because I'm using like this session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

Comment: then you just do 2 things 1.include_once 'dbconnect.php'; 2. replace $conn->query($query) by mysql_query($query)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92800/discussion-between-edmhar-and-shaymol-bapary).

Comment: how about the $num = mysqli_num_rows($conn->query($query)); ?

Comment: $num = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));